# Add dynamic list of Slivers returned by a function in CustomScrollView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I am trying to add a dynamic list of Sliverlist in CustomScrollView but it doesn't seem to work. The method correctly returns the list of slivers, which I verified by debugging. Here is the sample code of what I am trying to achieve

```
CustomScrollView(
          key: PageStorageKey<String>(myKey),
          slivers: _getSlivers(model.data, context),
        ),
```

Here is the _getSlivers metod:

```
List<Widget> _getSlivers(List myList, BuildContext context) 
{
  List<Widget> slivers = myList.map((key) => SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                   buildRow(index)
                  }
                },
                childCount: myList.length,
              ),
            ),
      ).toList();
    return slivers;
   }
 }
```

Comment: nick, you mean the scroll doesn't work?

Comment: no, the list doesn't even show

Comment: okay, check out the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `_getSlivers` is not correct,

- few errors with extra braces (could be typos)
- you should return your `buildRow`
- you should return `SliverList`

Not sure what your `model.data` or `buildRow` looks like but here is a quick example,

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<String> list = ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4', 'Title 5', 'Title 6', 'Title 7', 'Title 8', 'Title 9', 'Title 10', 'Title 11', 'Title 12', 'Title 13', 'Title 14', 'Title 15', 'Title 16', 'Title 17', 'Title 18', 'Title 19', 'Title 20'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: CustomScrollView(
                //key: PageStorageKey<String>(myKey),
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverAppBar(
                    title: Text('Test'),
                  ),
                  _getSlivers(list, context),
                ]
              ),
            ));
  }

  SliverList _getSlivers(List myList, BuildContext context) {
    return SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return buildRow(myList[index]);
        },
        childCount: myList.length,
      ),
    );
  }

  buildRow(String title) {
    return Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),child: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0)));
  }
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Oh!! that was a silly mistake from my side, wasn't returning build row. Thanks.

Comment: there is one more issue related to the above. I have to add SliverOverlapInjector in the "slivers" key of the CustomScrollView but when I add SliverOverlapInjector in the slivers list I am getting an error saying "SliverOverlapInjector is not a subtype of SliverList". Any idea about this?

Comment: nick, i need to see your code where you're doing that to know the exact issue but sounds like you're adding `SliverOverlapInjector` in `SliverList`. It should be in `slivers:` list like so, `slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(title: Text('Test')),
                    SliverOverlapInjector(),
                    _getSlivers(snapshot.data, context),` or if you're returning in the list of widgets then make sure you add it to the list.

Comment: You got it right Pro and I used the same solution but we cannot add list of slivers like the in the <Widget>[ ] array. It will only accept Widget and not List of widgets. I tried this and it worked. <Widget>[SliverOverlapInjector()]..addAll(_getSlivers(data, context));